# Получение html кода сайта с ajax

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, python-3.6, web-scraping

Необходимо получить html код вот [этой](http://www.solinberg.ru/catalog/sagitta_sredstva_dlya_pedikyura/) страницы. При получении код с помощью urllib.requests. Из-за динамической подгрузки в этом html коде не все наименования. С помощью Requests оправил вот такой

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://www.solinberg.ru/catalog/sagitta_sredstva_dlya_pedikyura/")
print(r.text)
```

Post запрос, который нашёл в режиме отладки в браузере, но получаю то же html код. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена указанием дополнительных параметров для Post запроса которые я нашёл с помощью расширения firebug для firefox.